# footer jumps only on first filtering action quicksand portfolio

Tags: jquery, css, footer, quicksand

I implemented a quicksand portfolio in a website (that I unfortunately work on in xampp so I can't show you an example) and my sitefooter does a big jump into the content area ONLY on the first filtering action.

**What I've tried:**

- various settings for quicksand's "adjustHeight" option
- avoiding css rules and jquery on the same selector
- defining widths and heights as good as possible
- W3C validation of my whole markup of course

**This is what happens:**

- load Portfolio page
- click on a filter
- full-width-footer at bottom jumps right up into the contentarea
- portfolio items rearrange and push footer back into its position
- use another filter
- smooth transitions, no footer jump

Additional info: I don't use px or em for widths but % because I needed columns and I needed the page to be responsive.

Why would the footer jump the first time using a filter only? Any ideas?

**Pieces of my HTML markup:**

```
<div id="main-content">
    <ul id="quicksand-portfolio" class="filterable-grid">  

        <li data-id="id-1234" data-type="category-1">
            <span class="portfolio-thumbnail">
                <a href="#"><img src="image.jpg"></a>   
             </span>                                

             <div class="thumbnail-overlay">
                 <div class="infotext">
                     <p>blablabla</p>
                 </div>
              </div>
        </li>

    </ul>
 </div>
```

**CSS Rules:**

```
ul.filterable-grid li {
    float: left;
    width: 30.68%;
    height: 180px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 3.97%;
    margin-bottom: 3.97%;
    position: relative;
}

ul.filterable-grid li:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 0;
}

ul.filterable-grid li:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: left;
}

ul.filterable-grid li p {
    display:block;
}

.portfolio-thumbnail {
    width: 100%;
    height: 180px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.portfolio-thumbnail img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

**And the quicksand part:**

```
// Quicksand Portfolio
function portfolio_quicksand() {
    var $filter;
    var $container;
    var $containerClone;
    var $filterLink;
    var $filteredItems

    $filter = $('.filter li.active a').attr('class');
    $filterLink = $('.filter li a');
    $container = $('ul#quicksand-portfolio');
    $containerClone = $container.clone();

            // Show Thumbnail Overlay on mouseover, hide on mouseout
    $('#main-content').on('mouseover', '#quicksand-portfolio li', function(){
        $(this).find('.thumbnail-overlay').stop().toggle('fast');
    });

    $('#main-content').on('mouseout', '#quicksand-portfolio li', function(){
        $(this).find('.thumbnail-overlay').stop().toggle('fast');    
    });

            // Filter Links
    $filterLink.click(function(e) 
    {
        $('.filter li').removeClass('active');
        $filter = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');

        if ($filter == 'all') {
            $filteredItems = $containerClone.find('li'); 
        }
        else {
            $filteredItems = $containerClone.find('li[data-type~=' + $filter + ']'); 
        }

                    // Quicksand Transitions
        $container.quicksand($filteredItems, 
        {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'easeInOutQuad',
            adjustHeight: 'auto',
        });
    });
}

if(jQuery().quicksand) {
    portfolio_quicksand();  
}
```

Comment: As it's an interaction / animation issue, a live example would be great.

Comment: Not very easy because I'm using wordpress and work in our local network BUT I will try to make a FIDDLE ready for you to look at... very nice, thank you!

Comment: Alright, I'm updating this: It seems to be an issue about the height of my `<ul>` that contains the portfolio items. When I set its height to a random px value, the footer does not jump. `100%` or `1px` does not work though.

Answer (score 0):

you can try adjustHeight: 'false'. it is working fine.